# What are the equations of the 3D transformation matrices?

Tags: matrices

Please have a look at the image below. There is a transformation matrix and graphical representation of 2 coordinate systems. I understand what the numbers in the matrix represent, but I can't figure out how we could write this in terms of equations.

[image: Link to image]

I've been watching MIT open course videos on matrices, and from what I've learned the numbers in the matrices are just coefficients of some equations. For example, if we had a system of equations like this:

$x_1=3 y_1+2 y_2$

$x_2=2 y_1+4 y_2$

Then we would have a matrix like this:

\begin{pmatrix}3& 2\\
2& 4\end{pmatrix}

So I'm trying to reverse engineer this matrix into an equation but can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you trying to find an equivalent system of equations to this transformation matrix, or are you trying to formulate a system of equations with which to compute the entries in the matrix?

Comment: I'm trying to find an equivalent system of equations to this transformation matrix

Answer (score 1):

The equation for this matrix comes from transformation rule:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\\1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}R_{11}&R_{12}&R_{13}&t_1\\
R_{21}&R_{22}&R_{23}&t_2\\
R_{31}&R_{32}&R_{33}&t_3\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{pmatrix} $$
$$
x_1=R_{11}x+R_{12}y+R_{13}z+t_1,\\
y_1=R_{21}x+R_{22}y+R_{23}z+t_2,\\
z_1=R_{31}x+R_{32}y+R_{33}z+t_3,
$$

Transformation matrix is usually presented as follows:
$$
A_1 =  \begin{pmatrix}R_{11}&R_{12}&R_{13}&t_1\\
R_{21}&R_{22}&R_{23}&t_2\\
R_{31}&R_{32}&R_{33}&t_3\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbf R&\mathbf t \\
\mathbf 0& 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\mathbf R$ is $3\times3$ ($n\times n$ in general) rotation matrix and $\mathbf t$ is a $3\times1$ translation vector.

If we expand the transformation rule
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf r_1\\1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\\1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}R_{11}&R_{12}&R_{13}&t_1\\
R_{21}&R_{22}&R_{23}&t_2\\
R_{31}&R_{32}&R_{33}&t_3\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
   \mathbf R&\mathbf t \\
\mathbf 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf r\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
we get an alternative way to present an affine transformation is like:
$$
\mathbf r_1=\mathbf R\mathbf r + \mathbf t
$$

So now we need to first deal with rotation (we forget about translation as if $\mathbf t=0$ or coordinate origins coincide). We see that if we take the vector $\mathbf i=(1,0,0)^\intercal$, then rotated vector $\mathbf i_1=\mathbf R\mathbf r=(R_{11}, R_{21}, R_{31})^\intercal$. From the picture we know, that $\mathbf i_1$ is looking down, so $\mathbf i_1=(0,0,-1)^\intercal$ and that help us to find the first column in matrix $\mathbf R$. We repeat the procedure for vectors $\mathbf j$ and $\mathbf k$ and find the row of matrix $\mathbf R$.

To find a translation vector is even simpler. The vector $\mathbf r=\mathbf 0$ will go to $\mathbf r_1=\mathbf t$, so $\mathbf t$ is just the position of new origin in old coordinate system. From the picture we see that $\mathbf t=(1,2,2)^\intercal$.

By arranging everything to the transformation matrix, we get the answer.

Comment: using the equation you wrote, wouldn't we get that x1=-y+1, which isn't correct?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't correct? Look at the end of the vector $j_1$. If unit vectors on the picture have the length $0.5$, then for $j_1$: $x_1=-y+1=-0.5+1=0.5$. Which is kinda of true: it ends in the middle of the box, just like vector $i$.